# How to check the value of eclipse properties like ${PROJECT_DIR_NAME}?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, pydev

I am using PyDev plugin for Eclipse. I see some properties like below:

[image]

I guess this is some eclipse built-in properties (not sure if this is the canonical name). I searched a bit but no luck.

Where are such properties defined? How to check their values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only pre-defined variable from PyDev: **PROJECT_DIR_NAME**.

Then there's "**ECLIPSE_HOME**, **PARENT_LOC**, **WORKSPACE_LOC**, **PROJECT_LOC**" from Eclipse.

Other variables have to be manually created by yourself in 3 different places:

1. String Substitution Variables associated to the project (in the project **properties > PyDev - PYTHONPATH** -- i.e.: in that same window in the rightmost tab).
2. String Substitution Variables associated to the Python interpreter (in **Preferences > PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter > rightmost tab**).
3. Path Variables in **Preferences > General > Workspace > Linked Resources > Path variables** (associated to the workspace).

The variables may be used for source folders or external libraries.

Related code: https://github.com/fabioz/Pydev/blob/bbe7874a527a583c5214ade594f45d4cc35d3ab7/plugins/org.python.pydev.core/src/org/python/pydev/core/docutils/StringSubstitution.java

Comment: I'm afraid I don't see how this answers the question, which is where is $PROJECT_DIR_NAME defined and how do you change it?

Comment: This is the project name... you can change it by changing the project name.